# Showing $\{h + Th: h \in H\}$ is closed under $T = T^* = T^{-1}$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

This is a part of a question (2.21) from *Elementary Functional Analysis* by Barbara D.MacCluer (GTM 253).

Suppose that $T: H \rightarrow H$ is an operator on a Hilbert space $H$ such that $T = T^{-1}$ and $T = T^* $, where $T^*$ is the adjoint operator of $T$. Show that the sets $$H_1 = \{h + Th: h \in H\}$$ and $$H_2 = \{h - Th: h \in H\}$$ are closed subspaces of $H$ with $H = H_1 \oplus H_2$, and the restriction of $T$ to $H_1$ is the identity $I$ while the restriction of $T$ to $H_2$ is $-I$.

Conversely, show that if $H$ is the direct sum of two subspaces $H_1$ and $H_2$ with $T(h) = h$ for $h \in H_1$ and $T(h) = -h$ for $h \in H_2$, then $T = T^{-1}$ and $T^* = T$.

---

I would appreciate it if my reasoning for $H_1$ is closed can be verified. Suppose $h_n + Th_n \rightarrow h \in H$. Then, $$h + Th = \lim (h_n + Th_n) + T\lim (h_n + Th_n) = \lim(2h_n + 2Th_n) = 2h.$$ That means, $h_n + Th_n \rightarrow h = h/2 + T(h/2) \in H$.

If this seems to be correct, where did I use the condition that $T = T^*$? Did I miss something?

Comment: For the converse you need to assume that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are closed. Otherwise the conclusion fails. For example let $f$ be an unbounded linear functional on $H.$ Fix $v$ such that $f(v)=1.$ Let $H_1=\ker f$ and $H_2=\mathbb{C} v.$ Then $H=H_1\oplus H_2.$ Moreover $D(T)=H,$ $T=T^{-1},$ but $T^*\neq T$ as $v\notin D(T^*).$

Comment: Thanks for the remark. May I ask how $H = H_1\oplus H_2$? Moreover, what did you mean by $D(\cdot)$?

Comment: The symbol $D(T)$ denotes the domain of the operator, in case it is unbounded. The decomposition of $w\in H$  is $w=[w-f(w)v ]+f(w)v.$ The first part belongs to $H_1$ while the second to $H_2.$

Comment: Thank you! I understand the decomposition. May I ask two more questions, sorry if they are silly - I am new to the functional analysis field.
1) I think the closed requirement is violated by $H_1$ in the example, since $f$ is not continuous, but $H_2$ is still closed, right?
2) Would you mind elaborating a bit more on why $D(T) = H$ but $v \notin D(T^*)$?

Many thanks!

Comment: $1)$ That's right. The space $H_2$ is closed as it is one-dimensional. The other space $H_1$ is dense in $H,$ therefore not closed. Concerning $2)$ we have $D(T)=H,$ as we set $T$ to be $I$ on $H_1$ and $-I$ on $H_2,$ so $T$ is defined on the entire space  $H=H_1\oplus H_2.$ Assume $v\in D(T^*).$ Then for $u\in H_1$ we have $\langle Tu, v\rangle =\langle u, T^*v\rangle.$ Thus $\langle u, v\rangle =\langle u, T^*v\rangle.$ As $H_1$ is dense we get $v=T^*v.$ On the other hand $-\|v\|^2 =\langle Tv, v\rangle =\langle v, T^*v\rangle =\|v\|^2$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question didn't explicitly specify that $T$ was continuous, so how to you know that $T \lim_n (h_n + T h_n) = \lim_n (h_n + T h_n)$?

In fact, continuity of $T$ follows from the fact that $T^* = T^{-1}$ so that $T$ is an isometry since $\langle T x, Ty\rangle = \langle T^*T x, y\rangle = \langle x, y\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks so much! I accidentally took for granted that $T$ is continuous.